# Unwanted blank space generated at the end of page

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a prob in my website. Whenever I click on a text box, an unwanted blank space is generated at the end of the page. Please help. link : http://connectorz.tk/
PS: I use the transition css effect. Maybe it has something to do with this? Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `pageBottom` to include position, width & bottom attributes. The problem I believe had nothing to do with your text boxes or content and was that your footer was not position to fix to the bottom and when the height of the viewport increased over 1200px that it was simply displaying the background colour set for the body because it ran out of stacked content.

```
/* PAGE BOTTOM */
#pageBottom{
 background: #666;
 padding: 1.500em;
 font-size: 0.750em;
 color: #CCC;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;

//ADDED
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
}
```